# SML syntax: `val rec` and `fun` compared to each other

Tags: syntax, sml, ml

What are the know things possible with one and not with the other? What are the known idioms to work around limitations of any one of the two?

### What I know of it

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862027/279335), Andreas Rossberg pointed to a restriction applying to `val rec` in SML: it must be of the form of an *fn‑match*, even when other expressions would make sense.

The `fun` syntax does not have such a restriction, but can't be used to introduce a simple binding (I mean, simply a name with an optional type annotation and nothing else), as it requires arguments to be exposed.

In an older question I lose track of, there was discrete comments in favour or `fun` over `val` / `val rec`.

I personally more use `val` / `val rec`, because it expose the distinction between self‑recursive and non‑self‑recursive binding (while what's exposed as self‑recursive may not actually be, the other way always hold, what's exposed as not self‑recursive is never self‑recursive), and also because it use the same syntax as anonymous lambda expressions (more consistency).

### The (all related) questions

These are the things I know. Are there others? I less know about any workaround idioms. Are they some?

Limitations of both seems to me to be syntactical only, and not have real semantic or soundness background. Is this indeed or are there semantic and soundness background for these limitations?

### A sample case (you can skip it)

If it's not abusing, I'm posting below a snippet, a variation of the one posted in the question linked above. This snippet expose a case where I'm having an issue with both (I could not be happy of neither one). The comments tells where are the two issues and why it's issues to my eyes. This sample can't really be simplified, as the issue are syntactical, and so the real use case matters.

```
(* ======================================================================== *)

(* A process chain. *)

datatype 'a process = Chain of ('a -> 'a process)

(* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *)

(* An example controlling iterator using a process chain. it ends up to be
 * a kind of co‑iteration (if that's not misusing the word). *)

val rec iter =
   fn process: int -> int process =>
   fn first: int =>
   fn last: int =>
      let
         val rec step =
            fn (i, Chain process) =>
               if i < first then ()
               else if i = last then (process i; ())
               else if i > last then ()
               else
                  let val Chain process = process i
                  in step (i + 1, Chain process)
                  end
      in step (first, Chain process)
      end

(* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *)

(* A tiny test use case. *)

val rec process: int -> int process =
   fn a: int =>
     (print (Int.toString a);
      Chain (fn a => (print "-";
      Chain (fn a => (print (Int.toString a);
      Chain (fn a => (print "|";
      Chain process)))))))

(* Note the above is recursive: fn x => (a x; Chain (fn x => …)). We can't
 * easily extract seperated `fn`, which would be nice to help composition.
 * This is solved in the next section. *)

val () = iter process 0 20
val () = print "\n"

(* ======================================================================== *)

(* This section attempts to set‑up functions and operators to help write
 * `process` in more pleasant way or with a more pleasant look (helps
 * readability).
 *)

(* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ *)

(* Make nested functions, parameters, with an helper function. *)

val chain: ('a -> unit) -> ('a -> 'a process) -> ('a -> 'a process) =
   fn e =>
   fn p =>
   fn a => (e a; Chain p)

(* Now that we can extract the nested functions, we can rewrite: *)

val rec process: int -> int process =
   fn a =>
      let
         val e1 = fn a => print (Int.toString a)
         val e2 = fn a => print "-"
         val e3 = fn a => print (Int.toString a)
         val e4 = fn a => print "|"
      in
         (chain e1 (chain e2 (chain e3 (chain e4 process)))) a
      end

(* Using this:
 *     val e1 = fn a => print (Int.toString a)
 *     val e2 = fn a => print "-"
 *     …
 *
 * Due to an SML syntactical restriction, we can't write this:
 *     val rec process = chain e1 (chain e2 ( … process))
 *
 * This requires to add a parameter on both side, but this, is OK:
 *     fun process a = (chain e1 (chain e2 ( … process))) a
 *)

val e1 = fn a => print (Int.toString a)
val e2 = fn a => print "-"
val e3 = fn a => print (Int.toString a)
val e4 = fn a => print "|"

(* An unfortunate consequence of the need to use `fun`: the parameter added
 * for `fun`, syntactically appears at the end of the expression, while it
 * will be the parameter passed to `e1`. This syntactical distance acts
 * against readability.
 *)

fun process a = (chain e1 (chain e2 (chain e3 (chain e4 process)))) a

(* Or else, this, not better, with a useless `fn` wrapper: *)

val rec process = fn a =>
   (chain e1 (chain e2 (chain e3 (chain e4 process)))) a

(* A purely syntactical function, to move the last argument to the front. *)

val start: 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = fn a => fn f => f a

(* Now that we can write `start a f` instead of `f a`, we can write: *)

fun process a = start a (chain e1 (chain e2 (chain e3 (chain e4 process))))

infixr 0 THEN
val op THEN = fn (e, p) => (chain e p)

fun process a = start a (e1 THEN e2 THEN e3 THEN e4 THEN process)

(* This is already more pleasant (while still not perfect). Let's test it: *)

val () = iter process 0 20
val () = print "\n"
```

Comment: Which limitations are you referring to, specifically, in your question? I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: @AndreasRossberg, the one which disallow to write `val rec process = chain e1 (chain e2 ( … process))` and the one which requires a useless application with `fun process a = (chain e1 (chain e2 ( … process))) a`. Unless I'm wrong, the first should type‑check, while after your answer in a previous question, I know why it's not possible to write this. I wanted to avoid unnecessary noise in these kind of cases, and wondered about `let rec` vs `fun` in the general cases. At least, I could get a kind of self‑documenting idiom (see my answer attempt).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `val rec` form computes a smallest fixpoint. Such a fixpoint isn't always well-defined or unique in the general case (at least not in a strict language). In particular, what should the meaning of a recursive binding be if the right-hand side(s) contain expressions that require non-trivial computation, and these computations already depend on what's being defined?

No useful answer exists, so SML (like many other languages) restricts recursion to (syntactic) functions. This way, it has a clear semantic explanation in terms of well-known fixpoint operators like Y, and can be given simple enough evaluation rules.

The same applies to `fun`, of course. More specifically,

```
fun f x y = e
```

is merely defined as syntactic sugar for

```
val rec f = fn x => fn y => e
```

So there has to be at least one parameter to `fun` to satisfy the syntactic requirement for `val rec`.

Answer (score 2):

I will attempt to start to answer my own question.

For the case of the forced use of a wrapper `fn` due to syntactic restrictions (may be an issue to consider adressing with [sML](http://successor-ml.org/) ?), I could find, not really a workaround, but an idiom which helps to make these cases less noisy.

I reused the `start` function from the sample (see question), and renamed it as `n_equiv`, for the reason given in comment. This would just require a few prior wording to explain what the η-equivalence is and also to tell about the syntactical restrictions which justify the definition and use of this function (which is always good for learning material anyway, and I'm planning to post some SML samples on a French forum).

```
(* A purely syntactical function, to try to make forced use of `fn` wrappers
 * a bit more acceptable. The function is named `n_equiv`, which refers to
 * the η-equivalence axiom. It explicitly tells the construction has no
 * effect. The function syntactically swap the function expression and its
 * argument, so that both occurrences of the arguments appears close
 * to each other in text, which helps avoid disturbance. 
 *)

val n_equiv: 'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b = fn a => fn f => f a
```

Use case from the sample in the question, now looks like this:

```
fun process a = n_equiv a (chain e1 (chain e2 (chain e3 (chain e4 process))))
…
fun process a = n_equiv a (e1 THEN e2 THEN e3 THEN e4 THEN process)
```

That's already better, as now one is clearly told the surrounding construct is neutral.

To answer another part of the question, this case at least is more easily handled with `fun` than with `val rec`, as with `val rec`, the `n_equiv` self‑documenting idiom cannot be applied. That's a point in favour of `fun` over `val rec … = fn …`

### Update #1

A page which mentions the compared verbosity of `fun` vs that of `val`: [TipsForWritingConciseSML (mlton.org)](http://mlton.org/TipsForWritingConciseSML). See “Clausal Function Definitions” around the middle of the page. For non‑self‑recursive function, `val … fn` is less verbose than `fun`, it may vary for self‑recursive functions.